# Disable selection richtextbox wpf

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Any clue how do we can implement it?

This link doesn't help a lot...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/d1132ee5-acad-49f3-ae93-19d386fe2d12

Comment: have you tried to disable focus? Focusable="False"

Comment: @Alex This is the answer man! Put it like an answer! Cool!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just disable focus

```
  Focusable="False"
```

or

```
  IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

if you need to hide selection

```
  SelectionOpacity="0"
```

Comment: Where do you set this? I've found no property of these in my RTF Text Box object.

Comment: @KarlDaniel - If you have a WPF project (not windows forms project!) than your RichTextBox should have this properties. XAML example: <RichTextBox SelectionOpacity="0" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>

Answer (score 5):

`Focusable="False"` works for you, but the cursor is still **selectable** so what you need is this:

```
Focusable="False"
Cursor="Arrow"
```

Answer (score 3):

`IsTextSelectionEnabled` is the property I'm using in WinRT...

Answer (score -2):

Did you try .IsEnabled = false;

Comment: The text is going to be in gray color. That's bad.

Comment: Then put that in the question.